# Android ListView populeted from SQLite, highlithing not working properly, when selecting an element from list

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I am kind of new to Android, I started working with SQLite 3 days ago. I managed to populate a list from database and defined some views following The Pragmatic Programmers - Hello Android, but I have a problem: when the list is displayed and I want to select an item it only highlights a line below and above the entry in the list. I am sure it has to do something with the definition of the lists row xml or listview xml. Though I will post the entire code.

validations_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/l_id"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/l_idcolon"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text=": "
 />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/l_name"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/L_namecolon"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text=": "
/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/av"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textStyle="italic"
 />
</LinearLayout>
```

testing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<!-- Note built-in ids for 'list' and 'empty' -->
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<TextView
android:id="@android:id/empty"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/empty" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the code for my activity:

```
public class LinesListActivity extends ListActivity {

private static final String TAG = "ValidationsListActivity";
private static int [] TO = {R.id.l_id,R.id.l_name,R.id.av};


private DbManipulator dbm;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.testing);

    dbm = new DbManipulator(this);
    try
    {

        Cursor c = dbm.getLines();
        startManagingCursor(c);
        showEvents(c);
    }
    finally
    {

    }
}

private void showEvents(Cursor c) {

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new   SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.validations_list,c,FROM_V,TO);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}


@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    dbm.close();
}
}
```

And I have a style defined for my app, but when I change it back to normal style the problem stays, nothing actually changes.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are expecting... the background color to change while pressed?  The background color to change and stay changed?

Comment: Ok, the upper is what I get, and the lower is what I want : [IMG]http://i48.tinypic.com/28jjxj6.png[/IMG]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector defaults to showing behind the list which defaults to transparent, so you can see the selector through it.

You have set an opaque color for the background, so you need to set the selector on top.

Add this to your listview XML

```
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
```

That should fix it up.

**EDIT**

Ok, next trick.  Set up a color state selector.

1) Create a color list in your `values` folder, setting color names to their hex numbers:

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="blue">#2554C7</color>
    <color name="green">#347C2C</color>
</resources>
```

2) Create a selector in your `drawable` folder:

item_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
     android:state_pressed="true" 
     android:drawable="@color/green" />
</selector>
```

3) Finally, set the selector as the background of your list row elements:

```
android:background="@drawable/item_selector"
```

Using the above would cause the background of the list item you were pressing to turn green while pressed, leaving the text visible on top.

Comment: Yeah this works, but not as I expected. It puts the entire selector on the top of my list so I don't see anything when i select an item. I would like to select the item but just the background to change color, showing the same text on the top of the selector. Like this the selector is on the top of everything.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I am really happy that you helped me, I was struggling with this problem for 2 days and I started to give up.

Comment: Great to hear.  Could you do me a favor and accept the answer?  (Click the checkmark next to it).  That lets everyone know your issue has been solved and gives the person that helped you out credit for the assist.